# Unable to connect the database via web services

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I have a problem when connecting the Java web app RESTful with the database. The run is performed successfully, but when I set the data in the URL it does not insert it in the database.

When I tried the code without web services, and just connected with the database, it is inserted. I do not understand why the web service and the database do not perform together.

**URL looks like:**

> http://localhost:8080/IOSAPP/webresources/my/SIGNIN/1/ahlam/alrabeh/ahl.1/a@gm/asd

and after execution I received this:

> ff

**Source Code:**

```
      import java.sql.*;
      import javax.ws.rs.Path;
      import javax.ws.rs.GET
      import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
      import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
      import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

    @Path("my/")
    public class SIGNIN  {

        @GET
        @Path("SIGNIN/{id}/{firstname}/{lastname}/{username}/{email}/{password}")
        @Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public static String SIGNIN(@PathParam("id")int id,
                                    @PathParam("firstname") String firstname,
                                    @PathParam("lastname") String lastname,
                                    @PathParam("username") String username,
                                    @PathParam("email") String email,
                                    @PathParam("password") String password) {
            Connection myConn = null;
            try {
                //connection to database
                myConn =
                        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/BEMYEYES",
                                "root", "root");
                //create statement 
                Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
                String sql = "insert into blind (id ,firstname , lastname , 
                username, email, password) values('" +id+"','" +firstname +"','"+ 
                        lastname +"','" +username +"','" +email +"','" +password+"')";
                boolean x = myStmt.execute(sql);
                if(!x == true){
                    System.out.println("added successful");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println( "added not successful");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return "ff";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the console output?  You will always get a response of `ff` as you can read in the code, even if storing the data fails.

Comment: i do not understand is that what you point about :  Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Tomcat server started.
Incrementally deploying http://localhost:8080/IOSAPP
Completed incremental distribution of http://localhost:8080/IOSAPP
run-deploy:
Browsing: http://localhost:8080/IOSAPP
run-display-browser:
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)

Comment: What is the response you are looking for?

Comment: You will always get ff. as your returning a string "ff" at the last line of the code

Comment: i need the information that i put it in url shown in database

Comment: my question is can i use restful web services with mysql ??

Comment: and if it possible why is not working with me , is there any error in my code ?